# Using ResponseEntity Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I want to use the ResponseEntity without returning a body, only set status code and headers. The ResponseEntity is a generic class, do I need to specify the type in this case, and if, what should it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you don't, just do something like this

```
ResponseEntity responseEntity  = new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Would you mind explain why I don't need to specify the type? Is it because I don't use anything that needs it?

Comment: generics are not used at runtime, they are to provide compile time info and avoid casting errors. Look up type erasure, everything will just be an Object.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `return ResponseEntity<Void>`